# How to retrieve columns that end with one of characters in a list

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to learn SQL and figuring out a way to retrieve all columns whose name ends with one of characters in an a list (using JDBC queries):

```
public Map<Long, Set<Long>> groupCountriesBy(Set<Integer> countryIdLastDigits) {

    String query = "SELECT c.id FROM countries c"
        + " WHERE c.name LIKE '%[dea]'"
        + " GROUP BY c.name ";

    var args = new MapSqlParameterSource("countryIdLastDigits", countryIdLastDigits);

    ....
}
```

`WHERE c.name LIKE '%[dea]'` does return all columns that end with either d, e or a, but I did not manage to find a way to pass countryIdLastDigits to this SQL query.

Could you please share with me some pointers / hints? Probably I'm missing few SQL concepts / commands.

Comment: What is your underlying database?  You may need regex support for this.  But SQL Server can handle this using `LIKE`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Standard LIKE has no regex functionality.

Comment: Try using REGREX

Comment: I am on Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most SQL dialects have *left* and *right* string functions so perhaps something like

```
where right(col,1) in ('d', 'e', 'a')
```

will be all you need.